# Magento2: How can solve this error "{"error":"invalid_grant"} " on product save by admin?

Tags: magento2, products

When I am saving product by admin then it is showing error "{"error":"invalid_grant"}" and product is not showing in frontend also.
How can resolve this?

[image]

Comment: did you checked for error log in var/log ?

Comment: also there may be one possibility that some custom extension is causing this issue. You may check for custom module which are dealing with some third party api you may try by disabeling it so you can get exact idea where the problem is.

Comment: @Dhaval, Yes I have checked log firstly but didn't get any error/warning/message. Yes I will check third party module also. Thanks

Comment: we can thought of some module which is dealing with third party API that may be throwing this error.